# SQL add multiple calculated rows after using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, grouping

I have a table of data that looks like this:

```
|Agency|Rating     |AVG|
------------------------
|Army  |Exceptional|10 |
|Navy  |Very Good  |8.5|
```

And I need to pivot/count the number of each type of rating as well as calculate the totals and percentages of each rating category so it looks like this:

```
|Rating        |Army|Navy|
--------------------------
|Exceptional   |1   |0   |
|Very Good     |0   |1   |
|Satisfactory  |0   |0   |
|Marginal      |0   |0   |
|Unsatisfactory|0   |0   |
|Total         |1   |1   |
|% of Ex       |100 |0   |
|% of VG       |0   |100 |
|% of Sat      |0   |0   |
|% of Mar      |0   |0   |
|% of Uns      |0   |0   |
```

Using the following Query:

```
select RatingWords as Rating, case when grouping([RatingWords]) = 1 then 
'Total' else [RatingWords] end as [RatingWords], Sum([Navy]) as Navy, 
sum([Army]) as Army
from
(select ratingwords, agency,
CASE WHEN Average BETWEEN 8.6 AND 10 THEN 1 else 0 end as Exceptional,
case WHEN Average BETWEEN 7.1 AND 8.5 THEN 1 else 0 end as VeryGood,
case WHEN Average BETWEEN 3.1 AND 7.0 THEN 1  else 0 end as Satisfactory,
case WHEN Average BETWEEN 0.1 AND 3.0 THEN 1 else 0 end as Marginal,
case WHEN Average = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Unsatisfactory
from dbo.DOD_Average) as sourcetable
pivot
(
Count(exceptional)
for Agency in ([Navy], [Army])
) as PivotTable
group by grouping sets ((RatingWords),())
```

I get the following table:

```
|Rating        |Army|Navy|
--------------------------
|Exceptional   |1   |0   |
|Very Good     |0   |1   |
|Satisfactory  |0   |0   |
|Marginal      |0   |0   |
|Unsatisfactory|0   |0   |
|Total         |1   |1   |
```

So my question is, how can I add another group below the Total row to calculate the percentages? Or, if this is not the best way to create this report, i'm open to reworking it.

Comment: Will be faster if you add sample data already filed in http://www.sqlfiddle.com. or simple ddl like create table and inserts with sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your above query in a table variable and `UNION ALL` the percentage queries. Something like this:

```
Declare @table table (Rating nvarchar(60), Army int, Navy int);
Insert into @table 
select RatingWords as Rating, case when grouping([RatingWords]) = 1 then 
'Total' else [RatingWords] end as [RatingWords], Sum([Navy]) as Navy, 
sum([Army]) as Army
from
(select ratingwords, agency,
CASE WHEN Average BETWEEN 8.6 AND 10 THEN 1 else 0 end as Exceptional,
case WHEN Average BETWEEN 7.1 AND 8.5 THEN 1 else 0 end as VeryGood,
case WHEN Average BETWEEN 3.1 AND 7.0 THEN 1  else 0 end as Satisfactory,
case WHEN Average BETWEEN 0.1 AND 3.0 THEN 1 else 0 end as Marginal,
case WHEN Average = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Unsatisfactory
from dbo.DOD_Average) as sourcetable
pivot
(
Count(exceptional)
for Agency in ([Navy], [Army])
) as PivotTable
group by grouping sets ((RatingWords),())

Declare @army int, @navy int;
Select @army = Army, @navy = Navy from @table where Rating = 'Total';

Select * from @table
union all
Select '% of'+Rating, (Army/@army)*100, (Navy/@navy)*100 from @table 
where Rating <> 'Total'
```

Comment: This, along with some changes for my workflow got me going in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing query as a CTE, you can `SELECT *` from it, and follow that with a series of `UNION ALL` queries that get each of the percentage rows that you want.